# Eclipse(Kepler 4.3.2) on Mac is too sluggish

Tags: eclipse, macos, performance, osx-mavericks

---

**********Hope next release, Luna(4.4) will fix it.************

---

Scrolling texts in the eclipse main text editor is sluggish on Mac OS X (tested on 10.9 Mavericks, MBP 2013 late) in comparison to my Desktop(which uses Windows 7 64)

The speed of the scrolling is worse the larger the text editor's area is; with a small area (~200x200 pixels) the scrolling is smooth!

// I'm not good in English,so I pasted some other issues and modified.. :(

I've tried many times fixing this including eclipse.ini!!!!...
but nothing seems working out.

someone suggested a solution that sets scroll bars appear all times.
but, I think it's not fundamental solution...

It's so annoying.. :<

Comment: What size files, and how much ram does your computer have?

Comment: @aglassman  Xms256m / Xmx768m / MaxPermSize512M.. and hardware ram size is 8GB

Comment: What size are the files you are trying to read?  Are they 100s of MB, or just a few KB?

Comment: it performs poor regardless of file size. a simple file e.g 100line source.

Comment: Are you able to view the system resources while you're getting these problems?  This sounds like a system issue vs an eclipse issue.  I experience sluggish UI with eclipse as well, but only when eclipse is building a project, or my system IO is bogged down by another process.

Comment: Sorry, looks like the link was blocked for me by the server.

Comment: i've googled many issues related this problem, see this. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366471

Comment: Oh, sluggish occurs anytime. I think this is not system issue. Sublime2 or Xcode perform good. also scroll buttery!!!

Comment: You could probably run it in a VM of Linux, but that may be overkill.  It looks like they know it's a bug, so hopefully they'll fix in the next release!

Comment: Considering the linked issue, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366471  I very much doubt that to post the problem here will be of any use.

Comment: right, it's better wait release Luna(4.4) :#

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue on my mac, hoping they will fix it in next release.